# How do I make my footer sit at the bottom of my content?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my footer to sit at the bottom of all the content, regardless of how much content there is. I've tried many different approaches, but none seem to work for me. At first, I got the footer to sit at the bottom of content, but then there was "whitespace" below the footer because there wasn't enough content to make the footer reach the bottom of the screen. Now, I got it to sit at the bottom of the screen, but it will intersect content, like this:

[image: how it looks now]

I want it to sit below the second row of content, but I can't seem to get it to do that, while still sitting at the bottom of the content when there is less content. Here is a demo.

For the footer intersecting the content, check [here](http://criesval.tk/about.html)
For the footer not going to the bottom of the page when there is a little bit of content, check [here](http://criesval.tk/contact.html)

Here is the CSS for the footer:

```
footer {
bottom: 0;
height: 50px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Flexbox. Look it up. It's the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your are structuring your HTML code is incorrect. Right now you have:

```
<header></header>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<footer></footer>
```

What you need to have is something like this:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
  <!-- all your DIVs with the main part of your code should be in here -->
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

This CSS code is needed in order for the sticky footer to work:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -50px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 50px; 
}
.site-footer {
  /*your footer code here*/
}
```

Follow that structure should help get your footer to always stay at the bottom. Example code has been taken from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Trying this now. Will report results.

Comment: You sir, are a freaking genius. I never wanted to use a wrapper, but it somehow seems important. Well, thanks now I know not to skip steps.

Comment: Also, can you explain why the wrapper was needed? I tried adding the styles to the body but that didn't work.

Comment: The wrapper has the 100% height and negative margin that is applied specifically for the footer area. If you have your other code in the way (outside the wrapper) the negative margin gets applied to something other than the footer container.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a bit tricky, I think I've faced the problem before, not sure I've solved it properly. Now I would use javascript, I know it's not optimal since you'd also have to listen to the size of the body etc.

But it's basically an if/else case, if content's bigger than window's size, then footer's `position: relative;`, else it requires `fixed` or `absolute` position. Note that for the `relative` position to work you'd have to remove those `float: left;` on your `<div class ="rows">`...

Another alternative would be to use some kind of filler, to fill up the space, and always keep the footer `relative`, but that's the same problem, it has to be dynamically computed according to window's size.

It's quite similar to the centered height problem, not that easy to figure out

Answer (score 1):

You can try this floating footer solution:

Thanks

Eric Chang

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #page {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5;
    }
    #footer {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      bottom: 0;
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    Test here
    <br>

  </div>



  <div id="footer">
    Footer Here
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The footer is at the bottom in my browser in the second example. What Browser are you getting the errors on?

Comment: You miss understood what the OP is asking for. He wants the footer _not_ to be at the bottom in the second example, but below the (short) content. Besides: don't get this wrong, but why do you post this as an "answer"? This should have been a comment!

Comment: Please, use comments section (not answer) for clarifying questions

Comment: Do you have any other Divs which are not statically positioned? W3Schools -> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static. If no such element is found, the containing block is <html>:

Comment: Can't comment, can only answer due to REP. I think it should be the other way round, i.e. you can comment but not answer until 50 REP